# How to set the header cell widths in a GWT DataGrid

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

So I've built a working `DataGrid`, it loads my data without any issues. I pass a list of objects and they are mapped to the correct cells. 
I'm setting the CSS of my cells with, for example `TextColumn.setCellStyleNames("gwt-myStyleClass")`, this works great for the actual `DataGrid`data columns, but it doesn't affect the header. So the result is my data is nicely formatted, but the header on the `DataGrid` isn't aligned properly. 
See below: 
 [image: DataGrid header misalignment]

How can I fix this so the column headers widths match the data columns widths?

Comment: Have you tried [doSetColumnWidth](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html#doSetColumnWidth-int-java.lang.String-)? Like `dataGrid.doSetColumnWidth(0, "100px")`.

Comment: I have not! I'll give that a try. Thanks

Comment: could you provide a short code example of how you do the creation of the datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This is just a partial answer. I'm still missing something.

After you commit your data with:

```
dataGrid.setRowCount(list.size(), true);
dataGrid.setRowData(0, list);
dataGrid.setWidth(width);
dataGrid.setHeight(height);
```

You can apply styles from your `.css` file to the headers like so:

```
dataGrid.getHeader(0).setHeaderStyleNames("gwt-Name"); 
dataGrid.getHeader(1).setHeaderStyleNames("gwt-Email");
```

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same problem and I'm still trying to solve it.
As far as I have analyzed there are some issues with the modes "auto" and "fixed" for the tables.
The header is on a table for its own and one of the tables are in fixed-mode (width specified) and the other has "auto" set.
There is some hints about it in the documentation: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html#columnWidths

EDIT:
Hi there ... at least for me I found the problem.
First the problem itself:

- I've used fixed mode tables (GRID) with Width-values in Pixel
- Behaviour: The same pixel width in Header and in Column had diferent sizes
- couldn't found WHY!!

My solution:

- Use % values!!!
- Basically set the CSS-Style for the header and columns: 
  header.setHeaderStyleNames("myHeaderCSS");
  column.setCellStyleNames("myColumnCSS");
- In the CSS-File:

```css
.myHeaderCSS {
    text-align: left;
    width: 6% !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
.myColumnCSS {
    text-align: center;
    width: 6% !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

And also the remark from the documentation: take care of adding up all %-values of your columns to 100%

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I never managed to fully resolve this, it's quite frustrating!